# (Sphere Lemma) Hanf locality Lemma and locally threshold testability

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

I am reading the proof of Hanf's Sphere Locality lemma for (finite or infinite structures but with bounded degree), and I'm trying to understand the details of the proof!  I'm confused with the restriction for applying linear ordering. Why the use of linear order fails to define a finite neighbourhood (in infinite structures)?

Comment: It might be useful to have a reference for the proof of Hanf's lemma you are reading.

Comment: What is the "restriction for applying linear ordering"? Are you just asking why Hanf's theorem doesn't apply to infinite linearly ordered structures? This is because if the order relation $<$ is in the lanugage, then for any two elements $a$ and $b$, either $a<b$ or $b<a$, so $a$ and $b$ appear together in a relation, and hence they are only one step away in the Gaifman graph. This means that the structure does not have bounded degree (every element in the Gaifman graph has infinite degree), so the hypothesis of Hanf's theorem fails. But maybe this is not what you're asking...

Comment: @J.-E.Pin here is the reference that I'm reading: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540196900188 it's actually the proof of Lemma 3.5, which uses Hanf's or Sphere Lemma.

Comment: @AlexKruckman That can be actually! But let me be more clear. This is what I'm reading at this moment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540196900188 The proof of Lemma 3.5, which uses Hanf's or Sphere Lemma. What I want to do is to extend this result to the infinite setting, but in my logic one alternative way to express the infinity is to use the linear order in both directions (I mean horizontally and vertically). Now why in this case I'm not allowed to use Hanf Lemma?

Comment: @AlexKruckman To be a bit more exact, my structure is infinite pictures which are special case of bounded directed infinite graphs. So, my structure is bounded, but using linear order to express the infinity makes it impossible to use Hanf Lemma. IS your answer here in this case also the same?

Answer (score 3):

I'll take a crack at answering the question that you seem to be asking in the comments. I recommend you also edit your question to make it more clear what you're asking, so it doesn't get closed.

Hanf's theorem says that given a quantifier depth $n$ and two structures $A$ and $B$ **such that all of the balls of radius $3^n$ in the Gaifman graphs of $A$ and $B$ have size bounded by some finite number $e$**, we can test whether $A$ and $B$ agree on all first-order sentences of quantifier depth at most $n$ by counting instances of $L$-isomorphism types of balls of radius $3^n$ in the Gaifman graphs. That is, $A\equiv_n B$ if and only if for each isomorphism type $i$, $i$ appears more than $ne$ times in both $A$ and $B$, or $i$ appears the same number of times in both $A$ and $B$.

Here the Gaifman graph of a structure $M$ is the graph with the same domain as $M$ and an edge between two elements $a$ and $b$ if and only if they appear together in some tuple from $M$ satisfying some relation in the language.

Now that bound on the sizes of the balls in the Gaifman graphs is very important. If $M$ is an infinite structure linearly ordered by $<$, and if the order relation $<$ is in the language, then for any two elements $a$ and $b$, from $M$ either $a<b$ or $b<a$, so $a$ and $b$ are only one step away in the Gaifman graph. This means that even the balls of radius $1$ in the Gaifman graph of $M$ are infinite, and there's no hope of applying Hanf's theorem.

But I think your application is ok. Just from taking a quick look at the paper you linked to, it looks like a "picture" is a structure in the language $L = \{S_1,S_2,\{P_a\}_{a\in \Sigma}\}$, where we view the elements of the structure as the positions in a 2-dimensional array, with $S_1$ and $S_2$ as successor functions in the two directions and $P_a$ as labels (each position gets exactly one label).

In this case, there's no need to include a linear order in the language to ensure that your pictures are infinite. Any infinite picture will satisfy sentences expressing the following things:

- Every element has a unique successor under $S_1$ and a unique successor under $S_2$.
- Every element is the successor under $S_1$ of a unique element and is the successor under $S_2$ of a unique element.
- For every $n$, there are no cycles of length $n$ for $S_1$ or $S_2$. That is, we can't find $a_1,\dots,a_n$ such that $a_{i+1} = S_1(a_i)$ for all $i$ and $a_1 = S_1(a_n)$.

And any picture satisfying the theory above will be infinite. There's no problem applying Hanf's theorem to infinite pictures in this language, since there is a uniform bound on the sizes of neighborhoods in the Gaifman graph (each element has exactly $4$ neighbors - it's successors and predecessors in the two directions).